# Sending an HTTP Post Request with ESP8266

Tags: c++, http, arduino, esp8266

I am trying to make a POST request using my esp8266. I have set up a webhook and I am trying to call it using my esp8266. I have tried various methods but it doesn't seem to work.

I first tried to use the ESP8266HTTPClient Library but it didn't work.
I then tried to directly make the post request through the 'client.println' but it also didn't work. When I figured out that I can't send http requests to the webhook I set up, I started sending it to a local website that I made through express so it would be easier to test it. When sending a simple curl command I get the right response however when I try to send the http call through the esp8266 I can't.

Here is my attempt using the ESP8266HTTPClient library:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h> 
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

const int sensorPin = 4;

WiFiServer server(80);

const  String altLink = "http://localhost:3000/message";

const String ssid = "shefer 2.4GHz";
const String password = "1234554321";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid,password);

  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected, IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  HTTPClient http;
  http.begin(altLink);
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
  int sensorValue = int(analogRead(sensorPin)/128);
  if(sensorValue >= 0 && sensorValue <=3){
    Serial.println("Light is on, sending request");
    int httpCode = http.POST("Hello from esp8266");
    //int httpCode = http.POST("");
    Serial.println("HTTP Code: " + httpCode);
    if (httpCode != 200){
      Serial.println("Couldn't send the request, got code: " + httpCode);
    } else {
      Serial.println("Request was sent successfully");
    }
    http.end();
    delay(5000);
  }
 }
```

And here is my attempt directly making the post request through 'client.println'

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h> 
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

WiFiServer server(80);

const String ssid = "shefer 2.4GHz";
const String password = "1234554321";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid,password);

  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected, IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  WiFiClient client;
  String data;
  Serial.print("Requesting POST: ");
   // Send request to the server:
   client.println("POST /message HTTP/1.1");
   client.println("Host: localhost:3000");
   client.println("Accept: */*");
   client.println("Content-Type: text/plain");
   client.print("Content-Length: ");
   client.println(data.length());
   client.println();
   client.print(data);
   delay(50000);
 }
```

I expect the esp8266 to send a POST request but it doesn't. I have tried many things and I am pretty desperate. All help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should replace localhost with your IPv4 address on your PC network. for example for mine is 192.168.1.4

```
 "http://192.168.1.4:3000/cameraTest"
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't possibly work in either case because you're using `localhost` as your destination.

`localhost` means "self" - it refers to the computer that's sending the request. So does IP address 127.0.0.1. In this case they would refer to the ESP8266 your code is running on - not the web server you're trying to communicate with.

You need to use the actual name or IP address of the computer you want send the request to, not `localhost`.

Comment: Hey, you were right. I sent my request to a regular HTTP website, but know I keep getting -1 as my HTTP status code. Do you know anything about that?

Answer (score 0):

Include a termination println() after printing the data

```
void loop() {
   WiFiClient client;
   String data;
   Serial.print("Requesting POST: ");
   // Send request to the server:
   client.println("POST /message HTTP/1.1");
   client.println("Host: localhost:3000");
   client.println("Accept: */*");
   client.println("Content-Type: text/plain");
   client.print("Content-Length: ");
   client.println(data.length());
   client.println();
   client.print(data);
   client.println();   //HTTP request termination empty line
   delay(50000);
}
```